# How to conditionally init a const variable?

Tags: dart

I am trying to init a const variable differently based on another const string.

Code is not inside a class, just plain dart.

Only way I found is using the elvis operator but it's quite ugly and will become unmaintanable with many conditions to handle ...

How would you do it ?

`test.dart` called with `--dart-define CONTEXT=context-A`:

```
// can be : "context-A" or "context-B" or "context-C" etc ...
const contextString = String.fromEnvironment('CONTEXT'); 

const Context contextObject = (contextString == 'context-A')
    ? ContextA()
    : (contextString == 'context-B')
        ? ContextB()
        : ContextC();
```

Any other method (like calling an init method) fails with dart telling me that I cannot init a const variable with a non const method :(

Thanks

Comment: I would use the ternary operator as you're already doing.  Do you really have so many build variants that scalability is a problem?  Having more than a handful of build variants already sounds like a maintainability problem.

Comment: Yep thanks but even with only 3 cases, my eyes are bleeding :)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use the ternary conditional operator as you're already using; I don't think it's unreadable, and as long as you don't have too many cases (which itself would be a maintenance problem), the indentation creep shouldn't be too bad.

However, one alternative would be to abuse collection-`if`:

```dart
const contextObject = [
  if (contextString == 'context-A')
    ContextA()
  else if (contextString == 'context-B')
    ContextB()
  else
    ContextC()
];
```

which is formatted more nicely (as long as the expression is sufficiently long that `dart format` doesn't try to squeeze it all onto a single line). **However**, I don't recommend this because:

- You'll need to some extra overhead of using `operator []` everywhere to access the intended object.
- Equality comparisons are potential pitfall. `contextObject == const [ContextA()]` will work, but if `const` is accidentally omitted, it will never compare equal.

(At some point, perhaps [`if`-expressions will be added to Dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/729).)